# change path to ttkbootstrap json file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

I try to distribute a tkinter GUI while using ttkbootstrap.

The isse I have is, that it seems that the default path to the ttkbootstrap_themes.json file is in C:/User/Documents folder.

When I copy the file into my project folder I get an error that the file is missing.

Anyone knows a workaround for that so I can later on also compile it to exe and send it to other users?

I cant find any information about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:
`style = Style(theme='custom_name', themes_file='C:/example/my_themes.json')`